# Как разобрать возвращаемую строку?

Tags: java

Как разобрать возвращаемую строку, чтобы получить ключ и значение по каждой паре,при этом положить все это в коллекцию?

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Продукт {" +
           " Название продукта = '" + _productName + '\'' +
           ", Код продукта = '" + _productCode + '\'' +
           ", Марка металла = '" + _brandMetal + '\'' +
           ", Вес продукта = " + _weight +
           '}';
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте через split

```
 String [] tokens = toStringValue.split("{=,\\'}");
```

у Вас получится массив со значениями. Так же можно с `regEx`

```
String[] results = toStringValue.split(regex);
for (String result : results) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

UPDATE

не лучше ли создать функцию который возвращает в нужном формате? К примеру:

```java
public Map toMap() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Название продукта", _productName);
    map.put("Код продукта", _productCode);
    map.put("Марка металла", _brandMetal);
    map.put("Вес продукта", _weight);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Главное, после этого помолиться, чтобы в `_productName` не оказалось одинарной кавычки, запятой или знака равенства.

Comment: @TagirValeev не лучше ли создать функцию который возвращает в нужном формате?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,да на самом деле,лучше возвращать строку в том  виде в котором удобно использовать,чтобы потом не парсить.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще разбирать вывод `toString()` — путь в никуда. Неизвестно, специфицирован ли он, может ли поменяться. Лучше уж сериализовать и десериализовать объект хоть в JSON. Там хотя бы не будет разночтений, если кто-нибудь назовёт продукт как-то типа `"', Код продукта = '1234"`. Мало ли кулхакеров в мире.

Если разбирать эту строку — единственный возможный вариант, то более надёжное решение — это составить конкретное регулярное выражение, которое соответствует всей строке целиком:

```
private static final Pattern PRODUCT_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("Продукт \\{ Название продукта = '(.+)', Код продукта = '(.+)', "
                + "Марка металла = '(.+)', Вес продукта = (.+)\\}");
```

И использовать его так:

```
Matcher m = PRODUCT_PATTERN.matcher(product.toString());
if(m.matches()) {
    String name = m.group(1);
    String code = m.group(2);
    String metal = m.group(3);
    String weight = m.group(4);
    System.out.println("Название: "+name);
    System.out.println("Код: "+code);
    System.out.println("Марка: "+metal);
    System.out.println("Вес: "+weight);
} else {
    System.out.println("Что-то левое вы мне подсунули!");
}
```

Такое решение устойчиво даже к вышеупомянутому кулхацкерству, не говоря уж о более простых вещах типа запятой в названии продукта (`«котелок чугунный, малый»`).